Raising garage floor to house level
I am trying to convert an 11ft x 12ft space in my garage to a room and I’d like the floor to be level with the house and insulated. I’m trying to figure out the most cost effective solution. The concrete garage floor is 4” lower than the finished inside house flooring. The flooring I’ve been considering plus 5/8” plywood would take up an inch. This leaves me 3 inches to fill the space. I figured I’d start with plastic sheeting for a vapor barrier with joists on top and insulation in between. Am I able to put two 2x4s wide side down on top of each other to make up the 3 inches? Also, what type of spacing should I need (using 5/8 ply) and can the floor just sit on the concrete or should it be fastened to concrete….open to any possible solutions. Thank you all for the help.

"Am I able to put two 2x4s wide side down on top of each other to make up the 3 inches"? 2+2 = 4 surely?

@Solar, 2x4s are nominal and 1 1/2 inches by 3 1/2 inches in actual measurements.

@RMDman short changed where you are then: https://www.diy.com/departments/pack-of-15-total-15-units-50mm-x-100mm-4-x-2-sawn-redwood-timber-2-4m-length/0757284545337_BQ.prd

The type of flooring might be important also.  5/8 is not thick enough for quite a few floor tiles.

@RMDman the problem here will be finding 2x4s that are straight!  And even if they're straight, there's little guarantee that they'll remain so!

@Huesmann, The 2x4s are being laid flat...on the larger side. The can conform to the contour of the floor, that should be very flat. If they are not straight, that is not an issue.

@RMD if they're solidly anchored (bolted?) to the slab, AND the slab is flat, that might work.

The bottom course will be screwed into the concrete per the op's directions. The second course screwed and glued on to that. There is no indication that the floor is not flat as a normal poured concrete garage floor would be.

Your plan is sound. The question about being cost effective is the issue. There are other options that may cost less in materials but take a longer time to complete.  Such as ripped 2x4s and OSB rather than ply. ( Not my choice.)
If you are content with your plan, I would go with it. I would anchor the bottom 2x4 to the concrete, even though it does not need to be. Anchoring will just take out any possible creaks or pops because the concrete floor is not perfectly flat and level.
That said, remember a garage floor should be slightly slanted toward the outside.  That should not be an issue, as it is so slight that one usually does not notice it when walking on the concrete floor.  It should not be an issue when your platform is built either. However be aware if there is a need for something to be perfectly level in the new room. (Maybe like a large fish tank) If being perfectly level is an issue that should be addressed at the beginning of the project. (And asked in another question)
Just double check your measurements and use Pressure treated 2x4s for the bottom plates ( Not effected by moisture so as to rot). Spacing with 5/8 subfloor should be 16 inches max, 12 inches if you plan any tile.

Should I need pressure treated 2x4's still if I'm using plastic sheeting first? And the reverse...do I even need sheeting if I go with pressure treated?  Also, should I have concern of any type of sqeaking with the 2x4s sandwiched? Should I use any type of adhesive perhaps?

All good questions, but hard to answer without knowing the finish floor type and condition of the concrete.   the PT on the bottom  is if any water gets to it it will not rot and create a situation where the floor needs to be pulled up to repair.  I would do vapor barrier and pt if it were me.  Glue and screw if you feel the need.

I am being safe and doing the barrior, pt wood, and glue. Ended up deciding to rip 2x4s down and use 3/4 OSB with 16 in spacing.  Thank you for the suggestions!
